# How to install geforce drivers win 8 version on win 10?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I badly need to install a geforce driver windows 8 version on windows 10.So can anyone suggest ways to configure the nvidia installer in order to do so.I have a geforce 610M GPU.

Thanks for any solution

Comment: Why would you need/want to install the Windows 8 version drivers?

Comment: Why do you need to install incompatible Nvidia Windows 8.1 drivers on Windows 10?  Whats wrong with the Windows 10 drivers?

Answer (score 2):

You cant install a Windows 8 graphics driver on Windows 10.  However, NVidia does let you download older versions of any driver.  On the NVdia website, under drivers, they show a year's worth of drivers in the menu system.  You might be able to find even older ones, if you look hard enough.  You *might* even be able to call support and ask for a specific version or date, as I am sure they keep them all.